# custom global function not defined when testing in Jest; works fine when not testing

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, jestjs

I have a custom, globally-scoped function in my Express app, `foo`. When running my Jest `test` scripts, this function is caught as `undefined`. Thus, any tests using them fail.

`index.d.ts`:

```
declare global{
    function foo(): string;
}
export {};
```

`src/Utils/index.ts`:

```
global.foo = function foo(){
    return "bar";
};
```

`src/Modules/Example.module.ts`:

```
export const test = () => {
    // This will return bar, as expected, when developing.
    // A reference error will only be thrown when running npm test.
    return foo();
};
```

`src/Modules/Example.test.ts`:

```
import { test } from "./Example.module";

describe("modules/example", () => {
    describe("test", () => {
        it("returns bar", () => {
            let bar = test();
            expect(bar).toBe("bar");
        });
    });
});
```

Despite this not being an issue while developing, this test results in the error:

```
ReferenceError: foo is not defined.

export const test = () => {
    return foo();
           ^
    ...
};
```

Comment: Try `declare var foo: Function;` instead. If you want to keep the `declare global`, you need to add an export at the end: `export {}` so your file is marked as an external module. Right now, i think you are already in the global scope, so declare global does nothing.

Comment: @Lk77 This did not work, unfortunately. Same error.

Comment: Instead of making it a global function, why not export it and then import it where you need?

Comment: @Boguz The function I'm declaring can be used anywhere in my codebase. Having to import it into every file wouldn't make much sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify `src/Utils/index.ts` as a [setup file](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#setupfiles-array), which Jest will load and execute before running tests. You can add it to your Jest configuration file (or create one if you don't have one):

Assuming a CJS-format Jest configuration, jest.config.js:

```json
module.exports = {
  // Your other configuration options

  "setupFiles": ["<rootDir>/src/Utils/index.ts"]
};
```

It will look slightly different if you are using a JSON or TypeScript Jest configuration file.

However I don't recommend using global variables (even if you use them a lot). With a proper code editor setup, it is easy to import a function from another file.

Comment: Any reason, in particular, you wouldn't use global functions? I would much prefer to use `isNumeric(var)` over `!isNaN(Number(var))` without having to import it everytime.

Comment: A couple of reasons pertinent to this question: since the source file itself doesn't import the function, something else has to know about it and inject it into the environment, which is the cause of your problem here and is bad for modularity in principle. Also you have to define it in a .d.ts file and remember to update that if you change it. Also, any random NPM module might accidentally override your global function with its own, or accidentally call your function instead of their own.